# In Java, Does adding an else statement (after an already used if) take longer to execute?

Tags: java, performance, if-statement

Since an if statement is already evaluated anyway, does adding an else statement have any effect on performance?

A practical example:

```
if(updateTime >= updateIncrement)
{
    update();
    updateTime = 0;
}
else
    updateTime+=deltaTime;
```

vs:

```
if(updateTime >= updateIncrement)
{
    update();
    updateTime = -deltaTime;
}
updateTime+=deltaTime;
```

**Edit:** To clarify, I'm not looking for a micro optimization, this is just a hypothetical "how stuff works" kind of question

Comment: If you really think that the difference in performance between the two is significant (which I doubt): 1) Try decompiling the bytecode for the two to see if there is a substantive difference; 2) microbenchmark your code.

Comment: The snippet with the else statement is much more readable. Therefore you should choose it.

Comment: @Eran you removed your comment saying that the two have different behaviour - that was true, since we don't know the value of `deltaTime`.

Comment: @AndyTurner I removed it because I was wrong - the second snippet also sets `updateTime` to `0` if the condition is true (`updateTime = -deltaTime;` followed by `updateTime+=deltaTime;`) and adds `deltaTime` to it otherwise, only it does it in a confusing way.

Comment: @Eran ah, silly me, ofc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should always code for clarity first.  The first example, is clearer as to what it is doing.

The JVM optimises based on a library of patterns it knows how to optimise.  This means that in general, if you use common, simple idioms, the JIT will do a better job.  There are exceptions, but you should assume that unless you have profiled this code and it has shown up as a problem, it isn't worth complicating your code to "micro tune" it.

In short, there is a chance the first example is slightly faster as it is easier to understand.

Comment: That's what I thought too, the compiler will branch it anyway so taking the "else detour" is than either added to the if(false) branch and skipped in the if(true) branch. Is that a correct way of thinking about out?

Comment: @p.streef I am not sure it is useful to try to imagine what the JIT might do. Note: the x64 processor has a conditional-move instruction so an if/else might not have any branching. In any case, the CPU has branch prediction, so once the code has been run enough the condition not taken will cost nothing.